# win32 Pocket PC UI with multiple dialogs

Tags: winapi, user-interface, windows-mobile, dialog, pocketpc

Is it possible to develop win32 UI application for Pocket PC with multiple dialogs
we need to display each dialog based on user input and hide previous dialog when current dialog is displayed on window.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that sounds a lot like standard application behavior, which is supported.  The only thing not supported is MDI.  Programmatically it's going to work just like on the desktop, so examples using calls to [CreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931018.aspx) or [CreateDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms908169.aspx) will be applicable.